# How to pass google sheet header value into calendar event created from the form responses

Tags: google-apps-script

I have written a google App script to create a calendar event from the form responses , however when the calendar event is created the description should include the sheet headers(response from the form) for example currently my event is creates like below and these are values of  the description specific items I wanted in my calendar event

Test
Test 1
test 2

where as I wanted this to be created as below (here question 1 header of the sheet)

formquestion1 :Test
formquestion2 :Test1
formquestion3 :Test1

I had used  http://www.jessespevack.com/blog/2016/2/9/turn-a-google-form-response-into-a-calendar-event

```
function createDayEvent(eventObject)
        {
         if (eventObject.allDay == 'Yes')
            {
             var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(GLOBAL.calendarId),
             title = eventObject.title,
             startDate = moment(eventObject.startDate).toDate(),
             endDate = moment(eventObject.endDate).toDate();    
             var options = {description : eventObject.description +'\n'+ eventObject.formquestion1 + '\n' + eventObject.formquestion2 + '\n' + eventObject.formquestion3};
             var event = calendar.createAllDayEvent( title, startDate, endDate, options);
             return event;
```

Any help would be appreciated, as not an expert in scripting

Comment: Have you visited [this github post](https://github.com/dallashall/gcal-event-form)? Also, have you tried searching in [Google Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) for using [Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/) and [Forms Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/) techniques?

Comment: I did have a look , and I had built my script with similar instructions , it must be a small change thats needed to print the sheet headers along with responses

Answer (score 0):

HI Am able to get this working .

I had passed the Form response headers on the switch case code block and called the same in calendar event creation function

```
 switch () {
        case GLOBAL.formMap.description:{
        formQuestion1 = "FormQuestion1:";
        eventObject.description = formQuestion1+thisResponse;
        }break;
        case GLOBAL.formMap.option :{
        formQuestion2 = "FormQuestion2:";
        eventObject.option= formQuestion2+thisResponse;
        }break;
           } 
  }
```

which resulted the output as

[calender output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUNuP.png)

thanks 
Dinesh